# Handling assertions/exceptions using python-hypothesis

Tags: python, assert, python-hypothesis

What is considered to be best practice when it comes to property based testing using the `hypothesis` library with respect to assertions within the program code?

I created a very simple function to show my point. The function simply divides two numbers. I put in an assertion that fails if the denominator is zero.

When I run the test, it fails as soon as `hypothesis` chooses `0` for parameter `b` (denominator) due to the assertion error. However, the assertion in the function is meant to handle this particular case.

```
from hypothesis import given
from hypothesis import strategies as st


def divide(a: float, b: float) -> float:
    assert b != 0, "Denominator must not be zero!"

    return a / b


@given(b=st.floats())
def test_divide(b):
    assert isinstance(divide(100, b), (int, float))
```

How am I supposed to adjust the code to make the test pass for parameter value `b=0`? What's a pythonic way?

EDIT:
In my view, the suggested duplicate question ([Exception handling and testing with pytest and hypothesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57208801/exception-handling-and-testing-with-pytest-and-hypothesis)) doesn't solve the issue.

What happens if I were to use the following code?

```
@given(b=st.floats())
def test_divide(b):
    try:
        assert isinstance(divide(100, b), (int, float))
    except AssertionError:
        assume(False)
```

As far as I understand it, as soon as the assertion within the `try` block will be `False`, the `except`-path will be executed and the particular test case will be ignored. That is, every real test failure (found by `hypothesis`) will be ignored.

Compared to the suggested duplicate question, my `divide`-function will throw an `AssertionError` rather than a `ZeroDivisionError` for `b=0`. Every other failing test case will also cause an `AssertionError` (`try`-block).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception handling and testing with pytest and hypothesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57208801/exception-handling-and-testing-with-pytest-and-hypothesis)

Comment: I don't think so. I edited my original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@given(b=st.floats())
def test_divide(b):
    assume(b != 0)
    assert isinstance(divide(100, b), (int, float))
```

assume tells hypothesis that `b == 0` is a bad example, and to ignore it.

Bear in mind that with the floats strategy, you're also going to get `Nan` and `-Nan` - you can disable this in the strat with `allow_infinity=False`. Once you're modifying the strat, you may as well also add `min_value=1` or `min_value=0.00000001` to prevent `0`

Comment: You probably want `allow_nan=False` to exclude `nan`; `allow_infinity=False` would instead disable `+inf` and `-inf` ;-)